# AWS Point a domain name to both cloud front and an API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway, domain-name

So, I've used things like Route 53 before. I have a project now where there will be a website that is served over static pages but uses Javascript to hit an API. The static pages are stored in S3 cached behind cloudfront, the api is an API gateway tied to some backend logic.

How can I make it so www.site.com points to the cloudfront-attached S3 instances, but www.site.com/api/ redirects to my api? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If instead of `www.site.com/api` you used `api.site.com` or some similar subdomain, you wouldn't need to point a CF distribution at the APIGW API.

APIGW is already fronted by a CF distribution; the Custom Domain Name feature allows you to import an SSL Cert which is attached to the existing CF distribution. Then APIGW provides the domain name of the CF distribution so you can configure a subdomain record like `api.site.com` to point at it.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do that using DNS.

Instead, you can use CloudFront to front both: the S3 bucket and the API.

1. Create a CloudFront distribution.
2. Set it's alias to www.site.com
3. Create one "behaviour" for `/api` and have it use an origin pointing to your API.
4. Have a second (default) behaviour for everything else and have it use an origin pointing to your S3 bucket.
5. Finally, use Route53 point www.site.com to your CloudFront distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this in AWS.

Create a `CloudFront` distribution, point your domain to `CloudFront` in `Route53`.

In the newly created distribution, locate the `Origins` tab, select `Create Origin`. Add a path `/api`, point it to API Gateway / an ELB / an EC2.

Then create another origin, add the path `/cdn`, point it to an s3 bucket.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.
I did it this way, but I have a serious problem. Trying to make a POST request with content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded directly to the api works, but pointing the cloudfront distribution to the api gives me request could not be satisfied error when I try to use it (example: stuff.cloudfront.net/test -> unique_id.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/test, then posting stuff.cloudfront.net/test/email to get the /email api part)